VS Code PHP extensions not working due to builtin PHP Language Basics extension
I'm trying to use snippets for PHP. I have tried the PHP, PHP Intelephense and PHP Awesome Snippets extensions. None of them works.
However, if I disable the builtin PHP Language Basics extension then the snippets start working. But I lose syntax highlighting in this case.

Also I noticed that snippets for opening and closing PHP tags (from PHP Awesome Snippets) works even when Basics extension is enabled. But snippets for switch, for loop and all other things aren't working.


Probably unrelated but here is my settings.json:
{
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "todo-tree.highlights.useColourScheme": true,
  "prettier.printWidth": 160,
  "editor.codeLens": false,
  "html-to-css-autocompletion.getSelectorsFromFileTypes": ["html", "php"]
}


Have you disabled "PHP Language Features"?

Yes, all of the above are all without PHP Language Features.
